# Vim highlighting stuck messed up for specific file

Tags: vim, vimrc, vim-plugins

I am using JSLint and Syntastic plugins for Vim, and I am having an issue where a specific file is stuck having broken highlighting and JSLinting, `foo/bar.js`. However, if I change the path such that it is `foo2/bar.js`, the highlighting issue is resolved.

I've tried remove `.viminfo`, reinstalling my plugins, and also checking out my file from the repository but nothing seems to be working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it being detected as some other type of file? What do you get if you type `:set ft?<enter>`?

Comment: Ah, I am getting `filetype= ` instead of `filetype=javascript`. How does this get messed up?

Comment: Check `.vim/filetype.vim`, and the contents of the `ftdetect` directory in `~/.vim` and any plugins that you're using.  Since the filetype isn't getting set that suggests that there may be an error. Perhaps try temporarily removing the previously mentioned files one at a time to try narrowing down where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entering `:set filetype=javascript` did the trick